# Laravel magic method for relationship returns the wrong related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my system, I have Role::class:

```
{id: 1, name: "admin"}
{id: 2, name: "user"}
```

The relationship with the User:class:

```
public function role()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

The user in question has a foreign key role_id = 2.

The problem is that when I write:

```
Auth::user()->role
```

I get Role model with id of 1 (admin), but when I write:

```
Auth::user()->role()->first()
```

I get the right result - id of 2 (user)

- I have looked at the raw query, it is ok
- The bindings are correct

Comment: try this `Auth::user()->role()->id`

Comment: when you do role(), it returns query builder, so this will not work.

Comment: Did the value of `role_id` change after you retrieved the user from the database?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing?

```
Auth::user()->role()->first()->id
```

Though it's better to use eager load on this one but that should work.

Comment: Thank you, this would be fine, but the problem seemed to stem from something outside the code I presented in the question.

Comment: I think it just as saying. hey the "Auth::user()->role" has a value which return 1 = true. Since the expected value of this is an object you may need to do the above code. But actually  using "Auth::user()->role->id" might also work.